# ¿Es la construcción "oler a + adjetivo" gramaticalmente correcta?

Tags: gramática

Creía que la construcción "oler a + adjetivo" no existía hasta que encontré el siguiente [párrafo](https://www.siberzone.es/blog-sistemas-ventilacion/malos-olores/).

> Se hacen más notorios cuando, al cruzar la puerta de nuestra vivienda,
>   sentimos lo que a veces se ha denominado como **olor a cerrado**.

Quisiera saber si es una construcción gramaticalmente correcta, como la construcción de "oler a + sustantivo".

Si ambas construcciones son correctas, ¿entonces cuál sería la diferencia de significado entre "oler a asco" y "oler a asqueroso". Muchas gracias.

Comment: "Huele a muerto" es una expresión muy común. Muerto es un adjetivo. Las dos expresiones que indicas no me parecen muy idiomáticas, aunque no sabría decirte porque en el segundo caso. En el primero: ¿A qué huele el asco que es una sensación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresión "oler a" se utiliza cuando el sustantivo o adjetivo que sigue establece un parámetro de **comparación**. De lo contrario, si se desea establecer una relación de **identidad**, no se usa la preposición "a".

Con ciertos adjetivos, la preposición "a" no es idiomática y el adjetivo funciona como predicativo subjetivo:

- El vino huele rancio. (Por su olor, el vino **está** rancio.)

Con la preposición "a", lo que sigue es un complemento de régimen, porque el verbo "oler" deja de ser cuasi-copulativo y se vuelve intransitivo preposicional. Se pierde la relación de identidad y se genera una comparación:

- El vino huele a podrido. (Por su olor, el vino **parece** podrido.)
- El vino huele a uvas frescas. (El vino huele **como** uvas frescas.)

Así, mientras en el primer caso la pregunta es *¿Cómo huele...?*, en el segundo caso también se puede preguntar *¿A qué huele...?*:

- ¿Cómo huele el vino?
- El vino huele rancio.
- ¿Cómo / A qué huele el vino?
- El vino huele a podrido / a uvas frescas.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones de verdad!